# How construct this regex to find multiline string ended with first occurrence of a string?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match all multiline strings that start with `"id="SomeDiv">` and end in `"<!-- someComment"`. My regex isn't working because `"<!-- someComment"` occurs multiple times, so it's matching everything until the last occurrence of `"<!-- someComment"`. I want to only match to the first occurrence.

**This matches to last occurrence**

```
'/id="SomeDiv">.*\<\!-- someComment/sim'
```

I also tried look-aheads and look-behinds (like the one below) but am doing it incorrectly as I get nothing.

**This doesn't match anything**

```
'/id="SomeDiv">.*(?!\<\!-- someComment)<!-- someComment/sim'
```

How would I match this properly?

**Example String**

```
//The string to search in
$str = '<div id="SomeDiv>Some stuff in here<!-- someComment --> More stuff<!-- someComment -->';

//What I **should** find:
$expectedResult = 'id="SomeDiv>Some stuff in here<!-- someComment';
```

Comment: @DanielGimenez That appears to work! Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it answered? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a lazy quantifier.  I added a grouping in case that was the content you were looking for.

```
id="SomeDiv">(.*?)<!-- someComment
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/pr23brsl)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lazy quantifier as Daniel Gimenez suggests it, or you can use this trick:

```
$pattern = '~id="SomeDiv"[^>]*+>\K(?>[^<]++|<(?!!--))*~';
```

explanations:

```
\K                   # reset all that has been matched before
(?>                  # open an atomic group
    [^<]++           # all characters that are not <, one or more times
  |                  # OR
    <(?!!--)         # < not followed by !--
)*                   # close the group and repeat zero or more times
```

Capture groups are not needed since the result is the whole match. Note that the \s modifier is not needed too since the dot is not used.